# IE element's height couldn't span its absolute-positioned flex container by min-height

Tags: css, google-chrome, flexbox, css-position, internet-explorer-11

I am making a simple page with a content-session that would span all the height of its container so that I can make a full-paged web. However, I need to make

1. the content's container (`div.inner`) absolute-positioned with `display: flex; flex-flow: column; min-height: 100%;`
2. the content-session (`div.content`) with `flex-grow: 1;`

to make it full-paged. (I need to make content's container absolutely-positioned to achieve futher fading content-switching effect)

Here is my code of implementation and I wonder why it is only working in Chrome but IE11. May I know if there any workaround for me?

Thank in advance.

```css
    html, body {
      height: 100vh;
    }

    .outer {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .inner {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: column;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      left: 0;
      min-height: 100%;
      background-color: lightgreen;
    }

    .no-span-content-upper {
      background-color: lightpink;
    }

    .span-content {
      flex-grow: 1;
      background-color: lightblue;
    }

    .no-span-content-lower {
      background-color: lightyellow;
    }
```

```html
    <html>
      <head></head>
      <body>
        <div class="outer">
          <div class="inner">
            <div class="no-span-content-upper">
              some dummy content without specific height
            </div>
            <div class="span-content">
              span content here
            </div>
            <div class="no-span-content-lower">
              some dummy content without specific height
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I test it on stackoverflow and the results is different between Chome and IE11. FYR: [https://imgur.com/cwGIA0x](https://imgur.com/cwGIA0x)

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT no, as you see IE11 rendered it different with what Chrome rendered

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT hey did you add `bottom: 0;`? don't add this

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT How come? I get it wrong even I run it directly...  [https://imgur.com/cEdHsTS](https://imgur.com/cEdHsTS)

Comment: sorry, my mistake. looks like I took the incorrect code for test.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I doubt you get @G-cyr running IE11 one which `bottom: 0`   haha

Comment: If possible for you than you can try to replace the min-height:100% to height:100% in the 'inner' class will fix the issue for IE.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT can't. Same as @G-cyr running IE11 answer. If the content is too much. It will overflow the `.outer` FYR: [https://imgur.com/zZW1Bay ](https://imgur.com/zZW1Bay )

Comment: Currently there is no any other work around available to avoid this issue with IE. If I will meet with any possible solution in future than I will try to provide you. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

<del>If you also set the coordonates `bottom:0;` , it works fine</del>  But obviously not for your case ....

```css
html, body {
      height: 100vh;
      margin:0;
    }

    .outer {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .inner {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: column;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      left: 0;
      bottom:0;
      min-height: 100%;
      background-color: lightgreen;
    }

    .no-span-content-upper {
      background-color: lightpink;
    }

    .span-content {
      flex-grow: 1;
      background-color: lightblue;
    }

    .no-span-content-lower {
      background-color: lightyellow;
    }
```

```html
<html>
      <head></head>
      <body>
        <div class="outer">
          <div class="inner">
            <div class="no-span-content-upper">
              some dummy content without specific height
            </div>
            <div class="span-content">
              span content here
            </div>
            <div class="no-span-content-lower">
              some dummy content without specific height
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

The solution, `height` or `min-height:100%` / `vh`  + `flex-flow : column;` requires a parent also set to 100% and flex column  to work in IE, it's one of its bug (if anyone wants to look for a duplicate) . To avoid it, you'll need an extra wrapper, usually the 2 wrappers involved are then `html` and `body`, but here because of the `absolute : position`, taking that element off the flow , you need to add an extra wrapper to be the absolute one . ;)

```css
html,
body,
.outer-buffer {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.outer {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.no-span-content-upper {
  background-color: lightpink;
}

.span-content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.span-content div:hover {
  height: 200vh;
}

.no-span-content-lower {
  background-color: lightyellow;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <div class="outer-buffer">
    <div class="outer">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="no-span-content-upper">
          some dummy content without specific height
        </div>
        <div class="span-content">
          span content here<br>
          <div>hover me to over flow container</div>
        </div>
        <div class="no-span-content-lower">
          some dummy content without specific height
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: We cannot do that as if we set it to bottom: 0, `.span-content` will be overflowed if the content is too much that exceed 100vh. Then everything after `.span-content` inside `.outer` will be misplaced.

Comment: @mannok , you should have clarified that in your question , its a known bug about flex-direction/flow : column and height or min-height which requires 2 inbricated element to make it work (do not ask me why, that's a Microsoft secret) . I focused on position:absolute at first.. answer updated .. and  off i am again.